# GTA V Using someone else's disc 1 to play my disc 2

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

A few months ago I purchased GTA V for my Xbox 360. The other day I purchased GTA V online for my cousin but only received Disc 2. I know I can get my money back and all, but I only paid $10 for it. Can I use my Disc 1 and install it on her Xbox 360 and then use the Disc 2 that I paid for on her 360 or are the disc sets coded so you cannot do that?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. The is no hard-coded link between pairs of install and play discs.